# Deploy a SSIS Package to ADF(Azure Data Factory) using SQL Server Authentication

Tags: sql-server, azure, authentication, ssis, azure-data-factory

I am trying to deploy a SSIS package to an ADF SQL Server. In the deployment wizard, when i want to Deploy our SSIS Package with SQL Server Authentication, it gives me the below error:

The operation cannot be started by an account that uses SQL Server Authentication. Start the operation with an account that uses Integrated Authentication. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 27123).

As far as I understand, it is saying that I must use Integrated(Windows) Authentication.so, i have tried to connect with Integrated(Windows) Authentication but we are unable to connect,it gives me the below error:

[TITLE: SQL Server Integration Services
Failed to connect to server
One or more errors occurred. (mscorlib)
Failed to resolve the UPN for the current windows account. (System.Data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMLLu.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have already created the Azure-SSIS Integration Runtime in ADF. If not, please find the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-deploy-ssis-packages-azure).

Once your Azure SSIS IR is in running status, open the SSMS.

In the Login page, keep the **Authentication** as **SQL Server Authentication** only. Provide the Login and Password for your Azure SQL Server.

Now, **Click on *Options>>* option in the SSMS connection and enter the SSISDB to connect to the database as shown below.**

[image]

It connects to your Azure SQL Database, and you see an SSISDB database and integration Services Catalogs.

[image]

If you would like to know step-by-step to lift and shift SSIS packages using ADF, please refer this [third party tutorial](https://www.sqlshack.com/lift-and-shift-ssis-packages-using-azure-data-factory-v2/).